# Möbius maps $M$ are exactly the analytic homeomorphism on the Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

where $M(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, and the Riemann sphere is obtained by stereographic projection between $\mathcal{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

I am very sure that this is true, but I can't prove it.

PS. I am new here, so any help with asking better questions is appreciated.

Edit: As Daruma pointed out, I am looking for analytic isomorphism, that is; homeomorphisms that are analytic. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you are looking for just homeomorphisms, then there are certainly many more. I think you mean analytic isomorphisms (i.e. homeomorphisms which are analytic/holomorphic). e.g. $z\mapsto \bar{z}$ is a homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere to itself.

Comment: Hi niko. We have plenty of material on the best ways to ask questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959

Comment: Here's another homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere that is not in $M$, in fact it's not even smooth as a function of $(x,y)$: $f(x+iy) = x + i \sqrt[3]{y}$ (for $(x,y) \in \mathbb C$); $f(\infty)=\infty$.